# Stop first countdown when second started

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a question.
When my Activity starts, the first countdown is running.
What I am trying to do is to stop the first countdown, when I press a Button, and then a second countdown runs.
The second part works, but I don't know how I can stop the first countdown.
It is not called by any Button, but it starts when the Activity is starting.

I hope you understand what am I talking about.
Sorry for my bad English.

Here is my code:

```
Button finnish;
TextView letter;
TextView textViewState, textVievCity, textViewRiver, textViewPlant, textViewAnimal, textViewName;
EditText editTextState, editTextCity, editTextRiver, editTextPlant, editTextAnimal, editTextName;
TextView textViewAnswer1, textViewAnswer2, textViewAnswer3, textViewAnswer4, textViewAnswer5, textViewAnswer6;
TextView timer, timer1;
public int counter = 120;
public int finalCounter = 10;
public int counterStop = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Button finnish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFinnished);
    finnish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            final TextView timer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewFinalCOunter);
            new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timer1.setText(String.valueOf(finalCounter));
                    finalCounter--;


                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    timer1.setText("koniec rundy");
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
    TextView letter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLetter);
    final String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "ł", "m", "n", "o", "p", "r", "s", "t", "u", "w", "z"};
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 23);
    letter.setText(letters[random]);

    final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTimer);



        new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (timer1 != null) {
                    timer.setText(String.valueOf(counterStop));
                } else {

                    timer.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    counter--;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setText("koniec rundy");
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a reference to the `CountDownTimer` if you want to stop it e.g.

```
private CountDownTimer firstCountDown;

firstCountDown = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000){...};
```

Then you can cancel the first count down by calling it in the `ClickListener` of the Button with [`CountDownTimer#cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel()) like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    firstCountDown.cancel()
        ...
}
```

Comment: Ok i understand but now how i can put results form "firstCountDown" into textView like i was trying to do before?

Comment: @MichalG You can use the `TextView` and get it from there by calling `timer.getText()`.